# Get value between html tags Xpath and HtmlAgility

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

So Far I am trying to retrieve the text between HTML tags for a certain website....

Say for instance I need to extract out the text between these span tags how would I go about that, I am receiving an error stating "the object reference not set to an instance of an object" here is the HTML

There is also HTML Code prior to this portion here; I don't know if that should make a difference.

```
<div class="thumbnail-details">
<ul>
    <li> … </li>
    <li class="product-title">
        <span class="thumbnail-details-grey">The Blaster Portable Wireless Speaker in Black</span>
    </li>
    <li> … </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So far my C# code is

```
    HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = hw.Load(@"http://www.karmaloop.com/Browse.htm#Pgroup=1");
        if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode text in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='thumbnail-details-grey']/text()"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(text.InnerText);
            }
```

Can I get some help here, I want to extract out  "The Blaster Portable Wireless Speaker in Black".

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  I'm guessing it's at the if statement and htmlDoc is null.  You can change the if statement to `if (htmlDoc != null && htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)` to get rid of that error if I'm right, but then need to find out why it isn't loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works just fine, but you'll have to load the right page to get it to work. The page you are loading uses an ajax request to load the results you see in your browser.

So instead of the url you are currently using you have to use:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = hw.Load(@"http://www.karmaloop.com/Browse?Pgroup=1&ajax=true&version=2");
```

Then your code works. I'm still looking for the place this request gets put together...

But the query looks rather easy to guess. For example the page `http://www.karmaloop.com/Browse.htm#Pdept=11&PageSize=30&Pgroup=1` request the url `http://www.karmaloop.com/Browse?Pdept=11&PageSize=30&Pgroup=1&ajax=true&version=2`. So all you have to do is use your url and build a new one starting after the `#`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Works as needed now, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using CsQuery (https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery/1.3.4) and then it's as simple as:

```
var doc = CQ.CreateFromUrl(@"http://www.karmaloop.com/Browse.htm");
var nodes = doc.Find("span.thumbnail-details-grey");
foreach(var node in nodes)
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
```

Comment: This here looks interesting, will have to look into CsQuery. Thank you